# Do I need to use a BaseClass for this scenario?

Tags: c#, inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

Basically I have a class called Asset which holds all the information for an Asset in my system. This can get quite big (Assets have Thumbnails, Filenames, Metadata, Ratings, Comments, etc).

On my results page, I list all the Assets that match a particular criteria which then can be filtered using jQuery.

I was finding performance issues in IE8 so the first thing I did was look at the Asset class and see what was not needed for displaying an Asset on the page. (Later I visited my jQuery and found that it was what was causing the performance issues).

So, when I stripped my class right down to basics, I made that the BaseAsset and derived Asset from that.

My question is, did I need to do that? was there any need?

I shall provide examples if necessary, but I am refraining at the moment, because the post could become quite big :)

Comment: How are you filtering? Is the data set stored in a JSON format, I feel like we need some more insight.

Comment: It sounds like you're passing everything from the server to the client and then filtering on the client side.  If you have a lot of data, that may not be possible or practical.  Filter on the server side and have changes to the filter re-query the server.

Comment: If your assets are containing _a lot_ of data (for example, if you're storing the binary data for thumbnails/images or many comments, it could explode in size) then it can cause some significant slowdown passing around that unnecessary data. If instead you pass the bare minimum (ID, name, rating) then load the rest asynchronously as they're displayed it might help.

Comment: Well, if the problem was with the `jQuery` code and not not the `Asset` class, then you probably didn't **have** to do this. When it comes to performance, you do as much as _needed_ and no more.

Comment: yes it is in JSON format, basically I return a collection of the Assets to the jQuery ajax function and then loop through the objects, doing what is needed. 

I am not storing the binary data, just the paths, etc so the size should not explode. But the metadata that is passed with the asset is at least as large as the asset itself.

With around 500 assets, it takes about 3 seconds to load and about .5 seconds to filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need a `base class` per say, I think what you need is to send **what you need.** It seems that the problem simply was the fact that you didn't **need** all of the data *all of the time.*

I know it's tedious, but only send *what you need*, **when you need it**, and you won't have any problems. When you *need* more data, then either load it asynchronously with an AJAX call, or even make another page that the user navigates to.

Comment: that is exactly what I was trying, so what I have done is sent the base class which has only the things I need for the results page. I couldn't think of any other way to do this, because it is an ajax call that is pulling the data back to the page.#

Comment: Ideally you will build models for each need. So, let's say I had a Car class with Make, Model, Year, and Weight - but my view only needed Make, Model, and Year displayed like (Year Make Model), I would build a model class with one property and transform the data into that model and then send that model back. Sure, I could have sent down the `Car` class and strung it together in JS, but why? Send *only* what you need **only when** you need it.